Nextjs 13 - How to use jwt to encrypt a payload, and handle that jwt in client and server?
I know this isn't a safe approach, but basically this is what I'm trying to do:

Encrypt a payload from user inputs in a jsonwebtoken, create a link and put the token in a search param.

Clicking that link calls an API that verifies the payload and decrypts it.

Do some DB updates using the payload.


Let's say I want to create a reset password link: I make a jsonwebtoken from a hashed password from the input, and his email, then decrypt that in a route handler and update the db with the new data.
I'm confused about the flow of how to use the private and public keys. Can I use private env variables (so not NEXT_PUBLIC env variables) in server components? What's the flow of private and public keys I am supposed to be doing? Using the jsonwebtoken library, how can I set certain public keys as "valid"?
Appreciate any help.
